# JavaScript/CRM issue: Need help filtering option set based on what is displayed in text field

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I’ve created a Javascript web resource to filter an option set using this article as a guide: https://neilparkhurst.com/2015/12/01/javascript-control-optionset-values/

I want to be able to filter the Opportunity Type (option set) field based on what is selected in the Owning Team (Text) field.  However, I keep receiving the following error when I try to run it:

[image]

Below is my code.  How can I fix this error so the code successfully filters the Opportunity Type?

```
var analytics = {value : 701, text : "Analytics"};
var auto = {value : 100000000, text : "Automation / IAC"};
var burwood = {value : 801, text : "Burwood Cloud & Managed Svcs"};
var healthcare = {value : 401, text : "Healthcare Advisory Services"};
 
 
function FilterOppType(all) {
  var pickList = Xrm.Page.getControl("new_opportunitytype");
  var options = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_opportunitytype").getOptions();
  var owningteam = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_owningteamtext");
 
  // *** Clear current items
  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    pickList.removeOption(options[i].value);
  }
 
  // *** Now add back just what is needed
  if (owningteam == "Healthcare") {
    pickList.addOption(healthcare);
  }
 
  pickList.addOption(analytics);
  pickList.addOption(auto);
  pickList.addOption(burwood);
}
```

Comment: What is your all parameter? are you passing it from crom?
Also error says could not find function, did you registered it on respective event? also for testing remove everything from your code and just adds alert message and see if you get the alert.

Comment: Hello, is there a better parameter I could be using rather than "all"? I just used the article I've linked to as a guide as I am relatively new to JavaScript. I did register it on the Opportunity form as an "OnChange" event for when the Owning Team is changed. I'll give the "Alert" a try and let you know what I find. Thanks!

Comment: if you are on latest version of crm (9.0 and above) better use execution context as parameter. did you managed to get alert?

Comment: Thank you. I deleted my code and added an alert, but for some reason the alert is still not showing. Any ideas how I can fix this? My web resource is enabled and the function is pointing to the correct library. Thanks!

Comment: `function FilterOppType() {
alert("This is an alert");
}`
Try this without passing any parameter. Fire your js on Load of page and see if you get alert.

Comment: @AnkUser, Yes, that does return an alert.

Comment: if it does then go 1 line at a time, keep adding small block of code and check where it fails. you could also add debugger in your code and then can debug you code in browser.